# How to include JS, CSS and other server-side utils to a HTML page in NodeJs using expressJs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I could not find any solutions that worked for me.

I am trying to create a simple microservices architecture with Node.js instances. I do not use Dockerfile. The homepage microservices displays correctly the html with CSS, JS. The gateway microservice does **not** load the CSS, JS (the page looks broken).

[homepage html here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/669Pg.png)

[gateway response html here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ1jR.png)

At the moment I have 2 microservices:

1. Express server that sends index.html as file. It loads correctly the page with assets (css, images, javascript). I have used `app.use(express.static('public'))`.

homepage:

```
const express = require('express')
const app     = express()
var path      = require("path")

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
})

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Homepage listening on port 3001!'))
```

2. Express server that receives requests and wants to deliver content to user. I am trying to create an API Gateway to filter traffic (on authentication for example) and write logs.

gateway:

```
const express = require('express')
const request = require('request-promise-native')
const app = express()

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Write logs in database
    const uri = "http://localhost:3001/"
    const result = await request(uri)
    res.send(result)
 })

 app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Public API Gateway listening on port 3000!'))
```

[Project structure with the 2 server files here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rl7c.png)

Any solution is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm if homepage (http://localhost:3001) is actually accessible in the API gateway microservice?

Please include your docker-file and docker-compose files.

Comment: @Ezekiel Thank you for the really quick reply. Apologies for not being clear. I have updated the post and added 3 pictures. Yes, the content is accessible in the API gateway microservice. Please see [gateway response html here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ1jR.png). I do not use docker-files at the moment. Just simple express instances.

Comment: How are you linking to the stylesheet files inside your homepage, i.e. `index.html` file?

Comment: @5aledmaged Thank you for responding. I had already imported the files in index.html. I think that this [video](https://youtu.be/tJO_snvnDB8) will explain better want I want to achive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you request the homepage from the homepage microservice and serve its html to the gateway microservice, all resources (i.e. styles, scripts and images) aren't loaded correctly. That's because in your `index.html` relative paths to resources are used, for e.g.

```
<link href="assets/styles.css"/>
```

so:

- In homepage microservice, `assets/styles.css` gets resolved to
  `//localhost:3001/assets/styles.css`, then express server serves 
  `assets/styles.css` from `public` directory since express is configured to serve 
  static files from the `public` directory:

  `app.use(express.static('public'))`
- In gateway microservice, `assets/styles.css` gets resolved to
  `//localhost:3000/assets/styles.css`, then express server tries to serve 
  `assets/styles.css` but returns an error because the express server in the gateway 
  microservice isn't configured to serve static assets from any directory.

A simple solution to this problem is to redirect all the calls to the `/assets` in the gateway microservice to `//localhost:3001/assets`, so `server.js` in your gateway will look like this

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const app = express();

// redirect /assets to localhost:3001/assets
app.get('/assets/**', (req, res) => {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:3001' + req.path;
    res.redirect(uri);
});

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Write logs in database
    const uri = "http://localhost:3001/";
    const result = await request(uri);
    res.send(result);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Public API Gateway listening on port 3000!'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your JavaScript, CSS and images be available for public use as all our files are hidden from client-side.

So What to do? Just **keep all your client-side JavaScript, CSS and image in public folder and make that public folder available for client-side** like:

```
//Using expressJs
//All your HTML will be in this folder.
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
//This is your HTML template to know more [what is ejs][1] and what's different between html and ejs or jade please do little research.
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//This is what makes your image, JS and CSS available to HTML page.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

**How to import files from public folder?**
Use following ways:

```
// location of all these files is in public folder like:
// public/min/css/bootstrap.min.css
// public/min/js/app.min.js
// public/images/image1.jpg
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/min/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/min/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the kind and detailed response. I have researched about ejs. I created views folder and used home.ejs in server.js. The same: on homepage I can see the styled document, but on the gateway I do not receive the public folder.  Please see the code [here] https://imgur.com/a/avFX7DO

Comment: updated my answer check it. also if you need a repo get it from https://github.com/navinbisht1992/navinAngular just modify it and remove angular.js plugins you won't be needing them and also its older version of angular.

Comment: Thank you again for responding. I had already imported the files in index.html. I think that this [video](https://youtu.be/tJO_snvnDB8) will explain better want I want to achive.